# Firebase + Aurelia: how to process the returned key=>value format by Firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aurelia, key-value

I'm retrieving the following structure from Firebase:

```
  "bills" : {
    "1" : { // the customer id
      "orders" : {
        "-KVMs10xKfNdh_vLLj_k" : [ { // auto generated
          "products" : [ {
            "amount" : 3,
            "name" : "Cappuccino",
            "price" : 2.6
          } ],
          "time" : "00:15:14"
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm looking for a way to process this with Aurelia. I've written a value converter that allows my repeat.for to loop the object keys of orders, sending each order to an `order-details` component. The problem is, this doesn't pass the key, which I need for deleting a certain order ("-KVMs10xKfNdh_vLLj_k")

Should I loop over each order and add the key as an attribute myself?

Is there a better/faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might be a little late (sorry OP), but for anyone else looking for a solution you can convert the snapshot to an array that you can iterate in your Aurelia views using a `repeat.for`, for example.

**This is a function that I use in all of my Aurelia + Firebase applications:**

```
    export const snapshotToArray = (snapshot) => {
        const returnArr = [];

        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            const item = childSnapshot.val();

            item.uid = childSnapshot.key;

            returnArr.push(item);
        });

    return returnArr;
};
```

**You would use it like this:**

```
firebase.database().ref(`/bills`)
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
        const arr = snapshotToArray(snapshot);
    });
```

Comment: A little late, but the right solution! Hopefully it'll help people who visit this question in the future. Thanks!